# Http failure during parsing Ionic (Angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make an update on my ionic (with angular) application and when I call the method I get this error : `Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/drafbie/1077&97667400`

I don't know what I'm missing in my application please help.

As you can see in the backend method I will get the employee number and the phone number to generate a new password after that I update the database password to the new one to let the user login with the new password that will be received by SMS  the backend part is work fine but the front has this problem that I don't know how to solve it

and here image for the error :

[image]

here the ts file :

```js
  validationForm(){
     console.log(this.Form.value.employeeN);
     this.ForgetPass.getPerson(this.Form.value.DECAFFE,this.Form.value.phoneNumber,this.Form.value).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
      })
    //this.router.navigate(['folder/Inbox']);


  }
```

here the ts service

```js
 getPerson(matricule,phoneNumber,data) {
    return this.http.put(this.url+`/${matricule}&${phoneNumber}`,data)
  }
```

here the method in the backend (nodejs-expressjs):

```js
router.put("/:Decaffe&:phonenumber", async (req, res) => {
    const saltRound = 10;
    const password = generator.generate({
        length: 8,
        numbers: true
    })
      console.log(password)
    const drafbie = await DRAFBIE.findOneAndUpdate({ DECAFFE: req.params.Decaffe },
        {
            $set: {
                MOT_PASS: await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRound),
                PHONENUMBER:req.params.phonenumber
            }
        }, { new:true }
    ); await drafbie.save();
    res.send(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on the backend Angular want to get the data us JSON:
if I change the `res.send(password)` by `res.json({"password":password})` it will work fine
that's all